# Does gc.collect release memory for variables that I've deleted?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

If I use `del huge_object` and after that use `gc.collect()` will it release the memory that is taken by `huge_object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it depends...

Long answer: it depends on whether `huge_object` was the last reference on the actual object. If it was (for example because it was the only reference that ever exists), the object will be marked as garbage collectable and its memory will be reclaimed by nect `gc.collect()`. But it could not be the case:

```
huge_object = Huge_Class()
x = huge_object
del huge_object
gc.collect() # does not free memory for the huge object
```

Only the reference has been destroyed, the object will stay alive as long as `x` will exist.