# del statemente + gc.collect() do not release memory

Tags: python-3.x, list, garbage-collection

The problem is "how to really free memory" in python, and the "del" statement plus a call to the python garbage collector seems to not do the job.
Suppose I had a code that looks like:

```
for i in (number_of_iterations):
    # here I create a huge list
    huge_list = func(...)
    output = func1(hugelist)
    #at this point I only need the output value and can delete the huge list
    del huge_list[:], huge_list
    gc.collect()
```

When I ask to "del" huge list I would like to get the same as the free() statement in C and have that memory immediately back. But this seems not to be the case and as I go through the iterations the memory consumptio increases.
If I trace the memory consumption through tracemalloc.get_traced_memory() (https://medium.com/survata-engineering-blog/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program-49f027e3d1ba) I observe that as theindex i increases, the available memory diminishes, as if it was not actually cleaned by the del + gc.collect() insttructions.

I read here: [Does gc.collect release memory for variables that I've deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237900/does-gc-collect-release-memory-for-variables-that-ive-deleted) that there may be a problem of references, but before the "del instructions if I ask to print:

```
sys.getrefcount(huge_list)
```

I get "2", but after the del instruction, if I re-try to print the number of references, I get:

```
NameError: name 'huge_list' is not defined
```

I'm then wandering, why is gc not releasing the memory occupied by huge_list? How can I solve the problem?